# Extract or manipulate a specific record from the database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I updated one table (UsedPartsTbl) with records from two different tables (InvPartsTbl & WrckPrtsTbl) whose data are of the same type (Auto Number). I tried to manipulate records from the UsedPartsTbl but due to the similar values of the data, my code is mistaking one for another. My goal is to just increment the Quantity by 1 if a similar record is already found in the UsedPartsTbl, regardless of which (either InvPartsTbl or WrckPrtsTbl) table I submit the record from.

The loop seems to recognize only the top/first record and then the code exits. And the increment is not achieved as my code is creating duplicates.

Note, I can't change the data types as the Auto Number suits my DB.

```
Sub CommitToInventory_Click()

Dim InvPartsTbl As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim db As Database
    Dim cp As Recordset
    Dim wp As Recordset
    Dim pStrge As String


    Set db= CurrentDB.OPenRecordset("UsedPartsTbl")
    Set cp= CurrentDB.OPenRecordset("InvPartsTbl")
    Set wp = CurrentDB.OPenRecordset("WrckPrtsTbl")
    
    pStrge = "Invoiced Stock"

    With Me.UsedPartsList

     ID_cp = .column(0)                    'PKey number for the InvPartsTble

     If DLookup("ID", "UsedPartsTbl", "PartID =" & ID_cp) = .Column(0) Then

     Do While Not cp.EOF

       If cp.Fields.Item(10).Value = pStrge And cp.Fields.Item(1) = ID_cp Then
  
          cp.Edit
          cp.Fields("QuantityUsed").Value = cp.Fields("QuantityUsed").Value + 1
          cp.Update


      Else 

         cp.AddNew
         cp.Fields("PartID").Value = .Column(0)
         cp.Fields("PartName").Value = .Column(1)
         cp.Fields("Source").Value = .Column(2) 
         cp.Fields("QuantityUsed").Value = 1                                                                                                                                                                       
         cp.Fields("Guarantor").Value = .Column(3)                                                                                                                                                                              
         cp.Fields("Storage").Value = pStrge 
         cp.Fields("StorageDate").Value = .Column(5)
         cp.Fields("Description").Value = .Column(6)
         cp.Update
                                                                                                           
    Exit loop                                                                                       
      End If
           
      cp.MoveNext
   Loop

End if

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Consider: `If Not IsNull(DLookup("ID", "UsedPartsTbl", "PartID =" & ID_cp)) Then`. However, seems to me instead of looping a recordset, UPDATE and INSERT action SQL would serve. If DLookup() returns match, run UPDATE, otherwise run INSERT. Or open cp recordset with filter for the ID. Check if recordset has records.

Comment: Saving balances to table is usually not advised. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: For what purpose are db and wp intended? They aren't used in procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to contain some anomalies.

First, always put Option Explicit on top of your code or put in on in the options. Alot of your variables are not defined.

Second, you define db as database than set it as a recordset. This can lead to unexpected behavior.

Third, combining data and adding it to a new DB is a real SQL task.

Fourth, be consistent - I see Fields(1), Fields.Item(1). Fields.Item(1).value, would basically be giving the same result.

That being out of the way, all your code is performed on the same recordset which is adding to itself and looping over records.
Next to that your code does not seem to change what it is comparing to so `.Column(0)` of some list (which is not defined see point 1). All your code is performed on the same recordset which is adding to itself and looping over records.

1. What recordset do you want to check?
2. What do you want to chech?
3. And to which recordset should it be added?

the solution using the above style would be:
Loop over all records in 1, check for 2, and add to 3

Comment: `.Column(0)` is defined by `With Me.UsedPartsList`.

Comment: Indeed its a tbl named list but it should be made a recordset to loop through each item I guess.