# Manipulate specific record from different recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have three (3) ListBoxes, wvListBox, ivListBox & cpListBox. All designed from three (3) separate Queries. wvListbox and ivListBox are designed to submit records upon a Double Click on each record, to the cpListbox. In a nutshell, cpListBox acts as a receiver for raw records sent from wvListBox and ivListBox, which act as the senders.

"QuantityUsed" is another Field/Column for all the ListBoxes and it measures the Double Click on the records. A Double-Click on the "sender" means a decrement to the Quantity of that record by 1 and an increment by 1 in the receiver. This is if there is already a similar record existing in the receiver. Else, a new record is added with Quantity being 1.

The Primary Keys for the Senders (wvListBox & ivListBox) are of the same data type (Auto Number). Records sent from these listboxes (Senders) cannot be uniquely manipulated. The code is mistaking one for the other.

So, I had to add another Field/Column named "Storage" to achieve a Composite Key. And this seems to work fine but the code seems to recognize only the top record by displaying duplicates in the receiver. The idea to achieve the increment for the similar record, sent from the same source is not achieved.

This is how best I could expound on my situation for your kind assistance.

Note that the snippet below is from the wvListBox's Double-Click Event

```
Private Sub wvListBox_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim InvPartsTbl As DAO.Recordset
    
    Dim db As Database
    Dim cp As Recordset
    Dim wv As Recordset
    Dim pStrge As String
    Dim ID_wv As Integer


    Set db = CurrentDB
    Set cp = db.OPenRecordset("committedPartsTbl")                   'Table for ListBox cpListBox
    Set wv = db.OPenRecordset("wreckedVehTbl")                       'Table for ListBox wvListBox
    
    pStrge = "Wrecked Part"

    With Me.wvListBox

     ID_wv = .column(0)                   

     If DLookup("ID", "committedPartsTbl", "PartID =" & ID_wv) = .Column(0) Then

     Do While Not cp.EOF

       If cp.Fields.Item(10).Value = pStrge And cp.Fields.Item(1) = ID_wv Then
  
          cp.Edit
          cp.Fields("Quantity").Value = cp.Fields("Quantity").Value + 1
          cp.Update


      Else 

         cp.AddNew
         cp.Fields("PartID").Value = .Column(0)
         cp.Fields("PartName").Value = .Column(1)
         cp.Fields("Source").Value = .Column(2) 
         cp.Fields("Quantity").Value = 1                                                                                                                                                                       
         cp.Fields("Guarantor").Value = .Column(3)                                                                                                                                                                              
         cp.Fields("Storage").Value = pStrge 
         cp.Fields("StorageDate").Value = .Column(5)
         cp.Fields("Description").Value = .Column(6)
         cp.Update
                                                                                                           
    Exit loop                                                                                       
      End If
           
      cp.MoveNext
   Loop

 End if
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you step debugged? Where is `End Sub` line? Why do you have tags vba6 and vba7? Code references "QuantityUsed" field, not "Quantity". This process is not making sense to me. Why is quantity used saved to table and not calculated from transaction records when needed? Edit question to show sample data as text tables.

Comment: This is a duplicate from yesterdays question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76205801/extract-or-manipulate-a-specific-record-from-the-database

Answer (score 0):

here is a reproducible example:

add some data to:

[image]

A and B send parts to C and Back

```
Public Sub adjustWarehouse(Warehouse As String, increment As Long, PartID As Long, CurrentQuantity As Long)
'silently fails if Warehouse is wrong
Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
If (Warehouse = "A" Or Warehouse = "B" Or Warehouse = "C") Then
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryUpdateWarehouse" & Warehouse)
qdf.Parameters("PartID") = PartID
qdf.Parameters("Quantity") = (increment + CurrentQuantity)
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
End If
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub


Public Function PartinWarehouse(PartID As Long, WarehouseAbbreviation As String) As Boolean
Dim returnvalue As Boolean
Dim WarehouseTable As String
WarehouseTable = "Warehouse" & WarehouseAbbreviation
returnvalue = Nz(DLookup("PartID", WarehouseTable, "PartID = " & PartID), False) 'PartID is truthy it evaluates to true
PartinWarehouse = returnvalue
End Function


Public Sub AddPartWarehouse(WarehouseAbbreviation As String, increment As Long, PartID As Long)
Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
If (WarehouseAbbreviation = "A" Or WarehouseAbbreviation = "B" Or WarehouseAbbreviation = "C") Then
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryInsertPartWarehouse" & WarehouseAbbreviation)
qdf.Parameters("PartID") = PartID
qdf.Parameters("Quantity") = increment
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
End If
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Saved Queries:

[image]

```
'don't forget to add parameters to the queries using the ribbon
'only table names differ between A,B,C query versions
PARAMETERS PartID Short, Quantity Short;
UPDATE WarehouseA SET WarehouseA.Quantity = [Quantity]
WHERE (((WarehouseA.PartID)=[PartID]));
```

[image]

```
'qryInsertPartWarehouseA

PARAMETERS PartID Long, Quantity Long;
INSERT INTO WarehouseA ( PartID, Quantity )
SELECT [PartID] AS PartID, [quantity] AS Quantity;
```

Now for the double clicks for A and C, B is similar to A

```
Private Sub lstWarehouseA_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Dim PartID As Long
Dim Quantity As Long
PartID = lstWarehouseA.Column(0)
Quantity = lstWarehouseA.Column(2)
If Quantity > 0 Then 'business rule quantity cannot be negative
If (PartinWarehouse(PartID, "C")) Then
Dim quantityinWarehouseC As Long
quantityinWarehouseC = DLookup("Quantity", "WarehouseC", "PartID = " & PartID)
adjustWarehouse "C", 1, PartID, quantityinWarehouseC
Else
AddPartWarehouse "C", 1, PartID
End If
adjustWarehouse "A", -1, PartID, Quantity
Me.lstWarehouseA.Requery
Me.lstWarehouseC.Requery
End If
End Sub

Private Sub lstWarehouseC_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Dim PartID As Long
Dim Quantity As Long
Dim StorageWarehouseAbbreviation As String
PartID = lstWarehouseC.Column(0)
Quantity = lstWarehouseC.Column(2)
StorageWarehouseAbbreviation = DLookup("WarehouseAbbreviation", "PartStorageLocations", "PartID = " & PartID) 'A or B
'business rule parts go back to their storage locations
If Quantity > 0 Then 'business rule quantity cannot be negative 'TODO decide whether to clear 0 inventory
If (PartinWarehouse(PartID, StorageWarehouseAbbreviation)) Then
Dim quantityinStorageWarehouse As Long
quantityinStorageWarehouse = DLookup("Quantity", "Warehouse" & StorageWarehouseAbbreviation, "PartID = " & PartID)
adjustWarehouse StorageWarehouseAbbreviation, 1, PartID, quantityinStorageWarehouse
Else
AddPartWarehouse StorageWarehouseAbbreviation, 1, PartID
End If
adjustWarehouse "C", -1, PartID, Quantity
Me.lstWarehouseC.Requery
Me.lstWarehouseA.Requery
Me.lstWarehouseB.Requery
End If

End Sub
```

Before :

[image]

After a few clicks:

[image]